# finding an absolute path from a supplied path in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to find an absolute path of a supplied relative path, and use a default one if one was not supplied

Originally I had `OUTPUT_PATH=${OUTP:-"/home/default/output/dir"}`
I can do 
`OUTPUT_PATH="$( cd "$(dirname ${OUTP})" && pwd)"` to get the absolute path

but if I combine the two to:

```
OUTPUT_PATH=${"$( cd "$(dirname ${OUTP})" && pwd)":-"/home/default/output/dir"}
```

I am getting a bad substitution error, why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `${varname:-default}` notation means "substitute the value of the variable named `varname`, if it's set and non-empty; otherwise, substitute the string `default`".

In your case, `"$( cd "$(dirname ${OUTP})" && pwd)"` is not the name of a variable, so `${"$( cd "$(dirname ${OUTP})" && pwd)":-"/home/default/output/dir"}` is not using the above notation; it's just gibberish.

Also, the `dirname` call doesn't make sense to me; I think you might be misunderstanding what that utility does.

Overall, I think what you want is:

```
OUTPUT_PATH="$(cd "${OUTP:-/home/default/output/dir}" && pwd)"
```

You'll also want some error-checking afterward, to ensure that `$OUTPUT_PATH` is actually set (i.e., that `cd` was able to move to the specified directory).

Comment: It would be worthwhile to note bash's `-L` and `-P` options for the `cd` command.  "Absolute path" could mean a couple of different things. Oh, and +1 for "just gibberish". :-)